# Samsung Syncmaster SA300 - no display

Tags: display

I bought a Samsung Syncmaster SA300 and it worked perfectly for a couple months. One day when I turned my system on all I got was the "check DVI" message.  The LED screen was functional, but no signal was showing on the screen.

I trying toggling between VGA and DVI, but this didn't work.  I then tried going back to a VGA cable and again toggled between VGA and DVI.  No dice.

I've tried DVI and VGA from multiple systems, to rule out a problem with my original graphics card.  Same result everywhere.

I hate to chunk a monitor with a good LED screen.  What component might have died inside the monitor to cause this to happen?

Comment: I don't know if it's the same issue, but my monitor stopped working a year or so ago, and I was able to fix it by replacing (almost) all the electrolytic capacitors (for a total expenditure of less than $10). Might be worth opening it up to see if any of them are bulging or leaking.

Comment: Same model as mine?

Comment: No, mine was a Samsung SyncMaster 204B. It's a fairly common problem from what I've read, though.

Comment: Problem fixed - it is a known firmware issue with SA300 series monitors made July 2011.  See my answer below for the easy fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My monitor is working again.  SA300 series monitors manufactured around July 2011 were shipped with bad firmware that causes the problem in my OP.

Updating firmware on the monitor fixes the problem.   See [22" 300 Series LED Monitor @ Samsung Support](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/SupportOwnersFAQPopup.do?faq_id=FAQ00046519&fm_seq=50330) and click [LED: Can I Update The Firmware On My SA Series LED Monitor?](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/SupportOwnersFAQPopup.do?faq_id=FAQ00046519&fm_seq=50330)

You'll need to download a Windows EXE containing the firmware update.  The process takes about 3-4 minutes.  When the firmware updater completes, the monitor will automatically power down.  When you turn it on again it will begin working again.

**Samsung Announcement:**

> Samsung has released a firmware update for Samsung SA series LED
>   Monitors. This firmware update is for improved performance (better
>   picture quality and PC compatibility).
>
> If you have one of these models, Samsung recommends that you download
>   and install the latest firmware update specifically designed for your
>   monitor.

**Affected Models:**

> S20A300B, S20A350B, S22A300B, S22A350H, S22A450MW, S23A300B, S23A350H,
>   S23A550H, S24A300B, S24A350H, S24A450MW, S27A350H and S27A550H

Comment: dumb question - how can you upgrade the firmware if you can't see what you are doing?

Comment: You connect the defective monitor to a two-monitor system.   You use the working monitor to do the [firmware update](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5-3nLtNF_Y).

Comment: I use my monitor to connect to a Ubuntu desktop and I do not have a second monitor. I ended up borrowing a Windows 7 laptop connected the monitor to it in extended mode and applied the firmware.